# mysql - updating rows between tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables with identical structure.

old_table looks something (example, not actual table) like this:

```
Name  -  DOB  - id
John  -  xxxx - 344
```

new_table looks like this:

```
Name  - DOB  - id
John  - 1980 - 344
```

Where the new_table has the DOB column filled in. The ID field (unique) and the rest of the structure is the same between tables. I want to update the DOB fields in the old_table with the values from the new_table where the ID fields are the same (so in the above example where the 'id'=344, etc, for all rows and ids).

I was thinking of using:
INSERT INTO old_table (DOB) SELECT DOB FROM new_table WHERE...

but then my mysql knowledge trails off. Should I even be using INSERT or can I use UPDATE here? And how do I only pull the DOB value from the old_table where the ID field = the ID field of the new_table?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE old_table, new_table
    SET old_table.DOB = new_table.DOB
    WHERE old_table.id = new_table.id
```

**EDIT**: Based on comment from OP

```
UPDATE old_table, new_table
    SET old_table.DOB = new_table.DOB
    WHERE old_table.id = new_table.id
        AND old_table.DOB = 'xxxx'
        AND old_table.field4 = '-'
```

Comment: this works great but what if I want to only update rows WHERE old_table.DOB = 'xxxx' AND old_table.field4 = '-' ?

Comment: @user410341: Simply add those conditions to the `WHERE` clause. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

use update
UPDATE `old table` ot set `DOB`=(select DOB from `newTable` nt where nt.id=ot.id)
something like that should work